# Why is my Django test failing when the view actually works?

Tags: django, unit-testing

I have a class based view that works as designed in the browser. I'm trying to write unit tests for the view and they keep failing. I'm wondering why. The view (the UserPassesTest is whether the user is a superuser or not):

```py
class EditUserView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, TemplateView):
    """handles get and post for adding a new AEUser"""
    template_name = 'editUser.html'
    title = 'Edit User'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """handles the GET"""
        post_url = reverse('edit_user', args=[kwargs['user_id']])
        usr = get_object_or_404(AEUser, pk=kwargs['user_id'])
        form = EditUserForm(initial={'is_active':usr.is_active, 'is_superuser':usr.is_superuser}, \
            user=usr, request=request)
        return render(request, self.template_name, \
            {'title_text':self.title, 'post_url':post_url, 'form':form})
```

The Test Case:

```py
class TestEditUser(TestCase):
    """test the AddUser view"""

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.user = AEUser.objects.create_user(username='shawn', email='shawn@gmail.com', password='test')
        cls.user.is_superuser = True
        cls.user.save()

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

    def test_get(self):
        """tests the GET"""
        self.client.login(username=self.user.username, password=self.user.password)
        get_url = reverse('edit_user', args=[self.user.id])
        response = self.client.get(get_url, follow=True)
        self.assertEqual(self.user.is_superuser, True)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'editUser.html')
```

I have 3 asserts in the test case. If I comment out the last two, and only assert that the user is a superuser, the test passes. For whatever reason, though, on the other two asserts, I get failures. The error I receive is:

`AssertionError: False is not true : Template 'editUser.html' was not a template used to render the response. Actual template(s) used: 404.html, base.html`, which leads me to believe the get_object_or_404 call is what's triggering the failure. Where am I going wrong with this test case? Thanks!

Comment: I feel stupid. I'm trying to pull the password from the user, which won't match (hash of password != 'test'). Replace password with 'test' in the login and everything works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test should be:

```py
class TestEditUser(TestCase):
    """test the AddUser view"""

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.user = AEUser.objects.create_user(username='shawn', email='shawn@gmail.com', password='test')
        cls.user.is_superuser = True
        cls.user.save()

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

    def test_get(self):
        """tests the GET"""
        self.client.login(username=self.user.username, password='test')
        get_url = reverse('edit_user', args=[self.user.id])
        response = self.client.get(get_url, follow=True)
        self.assertEqual(self.user.is_superuser, True)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'editUser.html')
```